# Gesture with views

Tags: objective-c, uiview, gesture

Please check out this link for my question 
http://www.freeimagehosting.net/ahb4y

My problem is about gesture and views in xcode. 
I want to make some visual effects to display views by different gesture in my app.

For Q1(the left image),  users drag down the view then a smaller view written " Updating" is show on top of the yellow view(similar to facebook)  , the "Updating" is a view or a label?

For Q2(the right image), is it possible to add 4 views (smaller size with different contents) inside a view at the same time?  For example, I swipe from left to right then show all view that effect I want to get? (Those smaller views are UIView connected to 4 other view controller? )

I want someone can give me a suggestion or a keyword for this situation then I can find more information, thank you :) .

Answer (score 0):

Please post unrelated questions separately.  I'll answer the first question (Q1) here.

There are probably at least three views involved: a view for the spinning progress indicator, a view for the text “Updating…”, and a view for the text “Last Updated: …”.  The views containing text are probably instances of `UILabel`.  Keep in mind that `UILabel` is a subclass of `UIView`.

It's also possible that all three views are inside a container view that exists just to hold those three views.

Comment: Thanks your comment, I want to find out that is a view or a label because I want the way to implement it.
The situation is , before the user drag down the "content view" , the status container(including the progress indicator , "Updating" etc) is hidden , after user drag down the content , the status container show , then something new will display in the content area